# How to fix appcompat gradle error? android 3.4

Tags: android, gradle

Having continuous problems with my gradle. The

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

is underlined in red

This is stopping me from continuing in my development (i'm still very new to android). My problem initially started with

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

being underline in red and causing an error, but changing my import to

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
```

cured the problem, but my gradle still is having build problems. I have android 3.4, and my gradle wrapper is 5.1.1. I have no idea how to stop the error from occurring and getting rid of my gradle errors.

I've changed it to alpha1, rc01 and tried downgrading the version but its not working.

The dependencies is where my problem is occuring:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha7'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I just want the gradle to full work and be able to move on haha, I've been trying to fix this for a while...

[image: [1]: https://i.imgur.com/ZYLhZQN.png "sync failed"]

Comment: Try replacing v7 appcompat with this `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`, after that, sync the project, clear cache and rebuild the project. Now check if the error persists, if it does, try manually importing the `androidx` version in your code.

Comment: How do you manually import androidx?

Comment: Try rewriting your code : `SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);` It should give you a suggestion to import the code you are writing from `androidx` library. Also, it appears that you may not have fully converted or are not using `androidx` library imports in your code. Try fixing the main problem first.

Comment: the androidx implementation has removed the error for appcompat in the dependencies but now my MainActivity which extends AppCompatActivity has every in red. Is this a result of the change to androidx? I'm also getting an 'ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha7'

Comment: Have you actually migrated your project to `androidx`? If not, [read this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). If already done, open the link I have shared and look for relevant `androidx` imports and change them. This is a usual sign to have everything appear in red when migrated to `androidx`. In that case, all you need to do is to manually rewrite the error code but this time importing it from `androidx`.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad thank you! I got it to work by replacing old imports with their suitable androidx counterparts. This simple fix has resolved my near 3 hour struggle... thank you very much haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still using older support libraries hence the errors persist even in the app level Gradle file. Add these to your Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
```

After replacing these with your current implementations in your Gradle, sync the project. After that, clean/rebuild the cache.

Now the code you have wrote is most likely going to give error because the code was using older support library which is no longer in your project. To solve it, you need to rewrite the error code but this time using `androidx` imports.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your project to androidx

Go to **Refactor** -> **Migrate to androidx**

Click on **Migrate**